# CSS list-style-position makes line breaks when I don't want it

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm a UX designer and I'm trying to code my resume in HTML and CSS as a side project, and I've been trying to put my bullet points inside the margin. When I use `list-style-position` in CSS the bullet points stay on one line and my text moves to the line below like in this image.

[image]

My code is structured like this right now.

```css
.expName {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.expName h5 {
  text-align: right;
}

.project1 li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="job1">
  <div class="job1-rolename">
    <h4>Role name></h4>
    <h5>Dates</h5>
  </div>
  <div class=project1>
    <h5>Project Role</h5>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p>description1</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>description1</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>description1</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you just remove the line `list-style-position: inside;` does that solve your probelm?

Answer (score 5):

This is because `p` tags are given `display: block` by default, give the p tags inside your li `display: inline` and you'll be fine!

```
ul li p, ol li p {
   display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the p from your li it works for me.
Just like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>description1</li>
    <li>description1</li>
    <li>description1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh this worked for me! I guess I'll just have to put the typography css into the li css as well in this case! Thank you so much!

Comment: It's not necessary the <p> tag inside <li> element if you only want to insert text. But if you need particular style to it you may need it. You can choose two ways. The first is to change <p> with <span>. The second, add a new css section with p {display: inline}. Hope it was heplful ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are just misisng p on your css should be .project1 li p like below. Let me know if this is what you mean.

```css
.expName {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.expName h5 {
    text-align: right;
}

.project1 li p {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="job1">
    <div class="job1-rolename">
        <h4>Role name</h4>
        <h5>Dates</h5>
    </div>
    <div class=project1>
        <h5>Project Role</h5>
        <ul>
            <li><p>description1</p></li>
            <li><p>description1</p></li>
            <li><p>description1</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm.. when I change the css it doesn't put the bullet points on the inside of the margin at all for some reason but it did fix the line break issue

Comment: interesting you can add display:inline as well. see if that works for you. or just what Dario's answer remove the p.