# CSS list-style-position makes line breaks on Firefox/Chrome but not on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have the following simple HTML to demonstrate the issue:

```css
ol {
    padding-left: 2ch;
    margin: 0.9ch 0;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="bodyContainer markdownContainer">
    <p>Some stuff some stuff stuff some stuff stuff some stuff stuff some stuff</p>
    <ol>
        <li><p>Item 1</p></li>
        <li><p>Item 2</p></li>
        <li><p>Item 3</p></li>
        <li><p>Item 4</p></li>
    </ol>
    <p>Bottom text</p>
</div>
```

**On Safari, this renders as:**

[image]

**On Firefox and Chrome, it renders as:**

[image]

As you can see, the list items are going into next line on Firefox and Chrome. Someone raised a similar issue here:

[CSS list-style-position makes line breaks when I don't want it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72984723/css-list-style-position-makes-line-breaks-when-i-dont-want-it)

However, they didn't have the question about differences in Safari and Firefox/Chrome.

The reason I added `list-style-position: inside;` was because of another issue which was also working differently between Safari and Firefox/Chrome. Without it, the `1. 2. 3.` bullet points were rendering outside only on safari and the `padding-left: 2ch;` was not sufficient only on Safari. This was causing the numbers to be clipped.

Why's this different between browsers? Do `p`, `li`, and `ol` tags work differently in Safari (inline instead of block as mentioned in that other question)?

Comment: I've edited your question so your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. Your code has an `<li>` which is `display:list-item` by default, and inside of that is a `<p>` which is `display:block` by default. I think that Firefox and Chrome are actually displaying this correctly for you and Safari might be the outlier here. A block level element *should* behave this way and be on a separate line.

Comment: @ChrisBarr so, that would be a bug in Safari?

Comment: Possibly, but if you really want paragraphs inside of a list item you'll need to change the display of one or both of those tags anyway. An alternative is to use a different tag that's already `display:inline` by default, like a `<span>` instead. It just depends what you goal is here.

Comment: @ChrisBarr Unfortunately, I can't change the tag as it's coming from `marked.js` library and changing it would require a custom handler which would be unnecessary work for this. I will go with changing the display. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: The problem is that marker boxes are poorly defined in CSS. Safari is treating the marker box as `display: run-in` which is not unreasonable. In you look at [caniuse for `display: run-in`](https://caniuse.com/run-in) you can see that Safari used to support some version of it, and this is likely a remnant of that support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it renders differently in different browsers AND you have a block level element inside of a non-block element, you'll need to change the display of one or both of those tags anyway.

An alternative is to use a different tag that's already `display:inline` by default, like a `<span>` instead. It just depends what you goal is here